# What does "limits on use and storage" in the ToS refer to?

Tags: support, terms-of-service

[Stack Exchange terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) section 1 currently reads:

> Stack Exchange retains the right to create limits on use and storage in its sole discretion at any time with or without notice.

and that's all - a single sentence in a separate paragraph.

What is it about? The use and storage of what and by whom does this cover?

Comment: SE owners don't want you storing 9GB of encrypted then base64-encoded personal files in your 'About Me' section. They own the servers, they pay for the storage, and they want to explicitly inform users that SE is not dropbox, or pastebin, or Google drive, or Bitbucket, etc.

Comment: The ToS is there to account for, and explicitly disallow, as many abusive use-cases as possible, so the relationship between the user and service provider is clear if/when the user oversteps the bounds of acceptable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and I do not speak for Stack Exchange.

Under "Accepting the Terms of Service", right above Section 1, it says:

> The Services are accessed by You (“Subscriber” or “You”) under the following terms and conditions

To answer your question, I would think that this:

> Stack Exchange retains the right to create limits on use and storage in its sole discretion at any time with or without notice.

means SE is has the right to limit *your use of SE* as well as *how much you upload to SE*.

Comment: So don't use the site too much or you may be denied :)

Comment: Well, maybe, but it then should be "use and storage of the service" or something like that.

Comment: My point is that the first part quoted above does specify "you" and "the service". AFAIK the site doesn't let you store anything other than image uploads - this is just wording to protect SE in case someone uploads too much or uploads offensive material. It allows them to remove that.